# UItableview each cell label want to hide and height should be change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[image]

Create tableview and design it in CustomTableCell **Name,code,continent,population** line etc. and got the values from web web services  **united states,usa,989898**,**north America** etc. In CustomTableCell design it. my problem name should be a canada means **code** and **continent** want to hide and display **population:979797** and height should be reduse. next **mexico** means want to display all values.**china** and **afghanistan** values should be **code**, **continent** hide. **Population**: Want to display. how is possible help.(My doubt: In tableview cell create a one label it display in all cell how to hide and display in each cell).help me. what want to do in cellforrow in heighforrow .Ple see the screen here.than Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,it is possible.You have to apply condition based on the country name in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
Like this

```
if(countryName isEqualToString @"Canada"){
     countryInfoLabel.numberofLines=0;
     countryInfoLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Population:%@",populationFromService]];
}
```

Insert the information in the label `countryInfoLabel` based on the country name and display it accordingly. use `\n` to move to next line in `countryInfoLabel`.

And to change the height of the cell dynamically use the  `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
Use the following code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return (countryName.frame.origin.height+countryInfoLabel.frame.origin.height);
}
```

Hope it will work.